# Protofuf c++ - Deserialized message has no data

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm not entirely sure i'm doing this correctly. If tried both Merge and ParseFromCodedStream.  Code and output below:

```
bool tcp_connection::readDelimitedFrom(
    google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyInputStream* rawInput,
    jvm* message, uint32_t* payloadSize) {

    DEBUG && (cerr << "------ readDelimitedFrom.begin " << '\n');
    // We create a new coded stream for each message.  Don't worry, this is fast,
    // and it makes sure the 64MB total size limit is imposed per-message rather
    // than on the whole stream.  (See the CodedInputStream interface for more
    // info on this limit.)
    google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream input(rawInput);

    // Read the size.
    if (!input.ReadLittleEndian32(payloadSize)) return false;

    DEBUG && (cerr << "------ readDelimitedFrom got size: " << *payloadSize << '\n');
    DEBUG && (cerr << "------   input.CurrentPosition: " << input.CurrentPosition() << '\n');

    DEBUG && (cerr << "------ "  << '\n');
    try {

        google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::Limit limit =
            input.PushLimit(*payloadSize);
        DEBUG && (cerr << "------ PushLimit:" << *payloadSize << '\n');

        // Parse the message.
        if (!message->ParseFromCodedStream(&input)) return false;
        DEBUG && (cerr << "------ MergeFromCodedStream" << '\n');
                  cout << "----------- size:" << message->ByteSize() << endl;

        if (!input.ConsumedEntireMessage()) return false;
        DEBUG && (cerr << "------ ConsumedEntireMessage" << '\n');


        // Release the limit.
        input.PopLimit(limit);
        DEBUG && (cerr << "------ PopLimit" << '\n');
    }
    catch (const std::exception &exc)
    {
        // catch anything thrown within try block that derives from std::exception
        cerr << exc.what() << endl;
        return false;
    }
    // Tell the stream not to read beyond that size.
    DEBUG && (cerr << "------ readDelimitedFrom return true " << '\n');

    return true;
}
```

Console out:

```
---- connection.start (disabling Nagle)
------ h.r.h 4 bytes
------ readDelimitedFrom.begin
------ readDelimitedFrom got size: 76
------   input.CurrentPosition: 4
------
------ PushLimit:76
------ MergeFromCodedStream
----------- size:0
------ ConsumedEntireMessage
------ PopLimit
------ readDelimitedFrom return true
```

Comment: Can you also show how do you obtain `rawInput` ?

Comment: boost::asio::async_read(socket(), mutable_buffers_1,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was that I wasn't adjusting the stream after parsing the header. Now I only peek the socket header:

```
char buf[HEADER_SIZE];
socket().receive(boost::asio::buffer(buf), tcp::socket::message_peek);
```

For anyone wanting to know the correct code:

```
ArrayInputStream ais(&m_readbuf[HEADER_SIZE], msg_len - HEADER_SIZE);
CodedInputStream cis(&ais);
jvm jvm;
bool isParsed = jvm.ParseFromCodedStream(&cis);

if (isParsed) {
    DEBUG && (cerr << "jvm:[" << jvm.name() << "] size:" << jvm.ByteSize() << endl);
    DEBUG && (cerr << "Got body:\n");
    DEBUG && (cerr << show_hex(m_readbuf) << endl);
    handle_request(&jvm);
}
else {
    DEBUG && (cerr << "didnt parse <----\n");
}
```